# Get Methods in Grails Controller

Tags: ruby, grails

I have some working ruby and javascript.  The javascript is this:

```
} else {
   $.ajax("/values/" + facet + "/" + searchTerm, {
       type:"GET",
   dataType:"json",
   success:function (res) {
       callback(res);
   }
});
```

Now I have a ruby method:

```
get '/facets' do
  content_type :json
  //return some json here
end
```

I am looking to write a groovy method that does the same thing, however I have never seen anything like this.  How do you write a method like this in groovy?  Thanks

Comment: I assume the Ruby is running in something like sinatra?

Comment: ya sorry, using the sinatra gem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say in your title (but not the tags) that this is in Grails...

So you'd want to add (inside `ValuesController.groovy`):

```
def facets() {
    String search = params.id
    render(contentType: 'text/json') {
        [ term: search ]
    }
}
```

That should return the json:

```
{ "term": "whatever searchTerm was in the JS" }
```

Comment: @dmahapatro Would that pick up the url from the question: `"/values/" + facet + "/" + searchTerm`